# How to stop get errors by typing ' mark

Tags: php

I have a dictionary page. when I search something the link showing as `index.php?word=(search word here)` but when I add ' mark to this link like `index.php?word=**name'**`

then showing this error Warning:

```
mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in...
```

how to stop this. and bypass ' mark

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you would want to use `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

However, I wouldn't recommend using `mysql_*` functions. I would use prepared statements with PDO or mysqli. You can find more info [here (PDO)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [here (mysqli)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 0):

quick fix would be to use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) against your query.

However, since mysql_* is deprecated, your best bet for future proof would be to use PDO or mysqli_*

Comment: mysql_eral_escape_string change it to mysql_real_escape_string